# how to pass my arguments to constructor smart contract while deploying using web3 truffle

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethereumjs, truffle-deployment, smart-contract-wallets

could you please help me with this step?
I have a smart contract with a constructor with a parameter, but I don't know how to pass this parameter when deploying the smart contract using truffle and web3.js
please I need this urgency for my project.
this the smart contract
and this the code to deploy the smart contract

voting.sol

/**************************/
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

contract Voting {

```
// Model a Candidate
struct Candidate {
    uint id;
    string name;
    uint voteCount;
}

// Store accounts that have voted
mapping(address => bool) public voters;

// Fetch candidates
mapping(uint => Candidate) public candidates;

// Store Candidates count
uint public candidatesCount;

// voted event
event votedEvent (
    uint indexed _candidateId
);

constructor(string _names) public {
    addCandidate(_name);
  
}

function addCandidate(string memory _name) private {
    candidatesCount ++;
    candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _name, 0);
}

function vote(uint _candidateId) public {
    // require that they haven't voted before
    require(!voters[msg.sender]);

    // require a valid candidate
    require(_candidateId > 0 && _candidateId <= candidatesCount);

    // record that voter has voted
    voters[msg.sender] = true;

    // update candidate vote Count
    candidates[_candidateId].voteCount ++;

    // trigger voted event
    emit votedEvent(_candidateId);
}
```

}

/********************
app.js

App = {
web3Provider: null,
contracts: {},
init: async function () {
return await App.initWeb3()
},
initWeb3: async function () {
if (window.ethereum) {
App.web3Provider = window.ethereum;
try {
await window.ethereum.enable();
} catch (error) {
console.error("User denied access")
}
}
else if (window.web3) {
App.web3Provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
}
else {
App.web3Provider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
}
web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
return App.initContract();
},
initContract: function () {
$.getJSON('/contracts/Voting.json', function (data) {
var VotingArtifact = data;
App.contracts.Voting = TruffleContract(VotingArtifact);
App.contracts.Voting.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
return App.render();
});
return App.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function () {
$(document).on('submit', '.form1', App.castVote);
},
render: function () {

```
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function (err, account) {

        if (err === null) {
            appAccount = account;
            $('#accountAddress').html('your Account :' + appAccount);
        }

    });
    var votingInstance;
    App.contracts.Voting.deployed().then(function (instance) {

        votingInstance = instance;
        return votingInstance.candidatesCount.call();


    }).then(function (candidatesCount) {
        let candidatesResults = $('#candidatesResults');
        candidatesResults.empty();
        for (var i = 1; i <= candidatesCount; i++) {
            votingInstance.candidates(i).then(function (condidate) {
                var id = condidate[0];
                var name = condidate[1];
                var voteCount = condidate[2];

                var candidateTemplate = "<tr><th>" + id + "</th><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + voteCount + "</td></tr>"
                candidatesResults.append(candidateTemplate);

            });
        }
        return votingInstance.voters(appAccount);

    }).then(function (hasVoted) {
        // Do not allow a user to vote
        if (hasVoted) {
            $('form').hide();
            $('#mhk').show();
        }
        else {

            $('form').show();

        }


    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
},
castVote: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var votingInstance;
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        var account = accounts[0];
        App.contracts.Voting.deployed().then(function (instance) {
            votingInstance = instance;

            var candidateId = parseInt($("input[name='vote']:checked").val());
            votingInstance.vote(candidateId, { from: account }).then(function (result) {
                location.reload();

            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
        }).then(function (result) {
            return App.render();
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    });
}
```

}
$(function () {
$(window).load(function () {
App.init();
});
});

Comment: Can you show where are you are deploying the contracts?
Also, can you format the question please!

Comment: Provided code doesn't deploy the contract. Truffle projects typically use a script from the migration folder.

Comment: do you can explain to memore

Comment: Hey there! They mean to ask if you can provide the Truffle deployment code you're working with. In addition, it's probably enough to cut out any contract code not relevant to the question - maybe keep the pragmas, contract names, and constructors. If there's a particular error message you're running into, please provide that too. Cheers!